# Nvidia colors to bright in Vista. How to adjust?

Tags: graphics-card, windows-vista, brightness

I have had this same issue with many GeForce videocards on different monitors (not sure about ATI cards) - default colors are too bright, greys become glowing whites. I have to run "Nvidia Control Panel" and then set gamma, brightness and contrast all to 0. The brightness becomes as it should be but I am losing all greys and color shades.

In good old XP days I had default nvidia color settings and everything was fine. All issues started somewhere from XP SP2 or so.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried fiddling with the Digital Vibrance settings in nVidia control panel? I'd reduce them, if I were you and check for changes.

[image]

Comment: I already have everything at 0 on this page.

Answer (score 0):

You could check the monitor settings and adjust them to your likings (not really sure on how to do that, but you could always google it =]

Answer (score 0):

just reinstall the nvidia drivers...i had this issue today simple re install sorted for me... im asuming its a gliched setting in the driver...as a reboot did not fix it...that or a third part application has changed the setting some how !